# vim. *(здесь курсор)<div ...props></div> и я хочу перейти в <div ...props*(здесь курсор)> и быть в режиме ввода сразу

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, visual-studio-code, vim

снова я с вимом вожусь. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на данный момент мне приходиться идти к концу строки возвращаться назад на символ и переходить в режим ввода. Что очень затратно, а если к примеру тэг только создался и на одной строке то только вариант с обычным перемещением. Есть ли варианты? И еще как вы перемещаетесь по странице? Я сейчас ищу эффективный способ чтобы бегать по словам а не строкам, то есть пробывал вариант с jumpy [image: введите сюда описание изображения]но расскаладка vim почему то перебивает поисковик по буквам. Еще один вариант - '/' очень удобно по идее, НО главный минус в расположении самого символа, у меня очень часто палец промахивается и приходиться руку выгибать что ужасно не удобно, в идеале было бы переставить сею функцию на другую команду но почему то не могу найти как это сделать. И пока остановился на варианте, который по идее может принести пользу, обычный vscode поиск - [image: введите сюда описание изображения] но все же там много лишней работы, к примеру, я ввожу поиск слова, мне нужно жать esc чтобы выйти с поиска и при этом та часть что была введена для поиска, остается выделенной и зачастую нужно еще жать esc чтобы выйти к примеру я хотел просто перейти к этом слову а не форматировать его. В общем ужасно)

Comment: работает) наверное следующий этап искать как сделать это за 2 клавишы)Спасибо! А как вы в vim переходите на слово которое вам нужно? И еще одно если не сложно, спасибо заранее, к примеру у меня  есть *(курсор)<div col={2}></> как мне перейти сразу к редактированию двойки а не идти туда через команды?

Comment: блин вообще кайф, могу просто нажать f2 и перейду к двойке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте команду `f`. Она ищет следующий введенный символ справа от позиции курсора.

А потом можно зразу перейти в режим вставки командой `i`.

Итого последовательность нажатий `f` `>` `i`.

Рекомендую почитать справку `:help navigation` там много чего полезного.

Comment: Спасибо что оформили ответ в правильной секции и спасибо за ответ!